# Spring Boot 1.3.0 Websocket with Spring Security DefaultSimpUserRegistry getSession NullPointerException

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-websocket

I am receiving the following NullPointerException from a 1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT Spring Boot application incorporating Spring Security and Websockets.

Version 1.2.3 of Spring Boot with the same code does NOT produce a NullPointerException.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.hash(ConcurrentHashMap.java:333)
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:988)
at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.DefaultSimpUserRegistry$DefaultSimpUser.getSession(DefaultSimpUserRegistry.java:179)
at org.springframework.messaging.simp.user.DefaultUserDestinationResolver.parse(DefaultUserDestinationResolver.java:153)
at org.springframework.messaging.simp.user.DefaultUserDestinationResolver.resolveDestination(DefaultUserDestinationResolver.java:101)
at org.springframework.messaging.simp.user.UserDestinationMessageHandler.handleMessage(UserDestinationMessageHandler.java:199)
at org.springframework.messaging.support.ExecutorSubscribableChannel$SendTask.run(ExecutorSubscribableChannel.java:135)
at org.springframework.messaging.support.ExecutorSubscribableChannel.sendInternal(ExecutorSubscribableChannel.java:91)
at org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:117)
at org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:104)
at org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate.sendInternal(SimpMessagingTemplate.java:184)
at org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate.doSend(SimpMessagingTemplate.java:159)
at org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate.doSend(SimpMessagingTemplate.java:47)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:95)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.convertAndSend(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:133)
at org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(SimpMessagingTemplate.java:224)
at org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(SimpMessagingTemplate.java:215)
at org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(SimpMessagingTemplate.java:201)
at au.com.ausgrid.powersense.device.controller.DeviceController.getDevice(DeviceController.java:95)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:111)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:799)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:728)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:168)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is being thrown when I submit a Http Request to kick off a long running task which sends updates using websocket messages.  When I submit an incorrect IP address for a device to process the above exception is thrown

```
@RequestMapping("/device")
public @ResponseBody void getDevice(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam String address, Principal principal) throws Exception {

    if (!InetAddresses.isInetAddress(address)) {
        TaskResponse tr = new TaskResponse();
        tr.setSuccess(false);
        tr.setMessage(address + "' is not a valid IP Address.  Please enter a valid IP Address");
        ServerTaskResponse str = new ServerTaskResponse(address, tr, null, ProcessorStatus.STOPPED_ERROR.getValue(), ProcessNextStep.ON_ERROR_ABORT.getValue());
        messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(principal.getName(), "/queue/device.error.config", str);
        return;
    }
```

I have the following WebSocket Configuration

```
@Configuration
```

@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

```
@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {

    registry.addEndpoint("/mapping")
            .withSockJS()
            .setSessionCookieNeeded(true);
}


@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/queue", "/topic");
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}


protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
    messages
    .nullDestMatcher().authenticated()
    .simpSubscribeDestMatchers("/user/queue/errors").permitAll()
    .simpDestMatchers("/app/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
    .simpSubscribeDestMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
    .simpTypeMatchers(SimpMessageType.MESSAGE, SimpMessageType.SUBSCRIBE).denyAll()
    .anyMessage().denyAll();
}
}
```

I have the following Security Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf().disable()
        .headers().addHeaderWriter(
            new     XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter(XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter.XFrameOptionsMode.SAMEORIGIN)).and()

        .formLogin()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/mapping.html")
            .loginPage("/login.html")
            .failureUrl("/login.html?error")
            .permitAll()
            .and()

        .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login.html?logout")
            .logoutUrl("/logout.html")
            .permitAll()
            .and()

        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/mapping.html").hasRole("ADMIN").and()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/stations.html").hasRole("ADMIN").and()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/internal.html").hasRole("ADMIN").and()

        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/assets/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()

        .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new ApplicationAccessDeniedHandler("login.html?denied"));

}


@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {


    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN","USER").and()
            .withUser("user").password("user").roles("USER");

}
```

My pom.xml file has the following dependencies

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Rossen Stoyanchev has implemented a fix for the NullPointerException in the Spring Framework Websocket DefaultSimpUserRegistry class [Fix NPE in DefaultSimpUserRegistry](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/c48e8708a7cc3117603f843166a3389c7ad16a07)

Answer (score 1):

this is now fixed in Spring Framework v4.2.0.RC1